# Automate VLC schedule recording

Tags: vlc-media-player

Can someone help me to Schedule a recording with VLC. My scenario is, I want to schedule record a stream from my dreambox to PC with VLC, I can do that manually but I want to automate it. I want VLC to launch at let say 22 Apr 13 at 18:00hrs record my stream from dreambox and save that stream on the PC and stop recording at lets say 22 Apr 13 at 19:00hrs.

This is the command I use to launch VLC and record a stream from dreambox to PC and save it to a file.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:31344 :sout=#duplicate{dst=file{dst=C:\\\\Users\\\\name\\\\Desktop\\\\JSC.ts},dst=display} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep
```

The above command if launched from command prompt will record the stream and save on PC. what it won't do is, it won't stop VLC at certain time or after certain period. you need to stop it manually.

Now what I want is to accomplish the above but with start and stop time.

Please can anyone give me step by step on how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the " --run-time=3600 " parameter like this

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:31344 :sout=#duplicate{dst=file{dst=C:\\\\Users\\\\name\\\\Desktop\\\\JSC.ts},dst=display} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep --run-time=3600 vlc://quit
```

It will run for about an hour (3600s)

Comment: Thanx very much the command worked, but how can i run this command automatically at a specified time lets say at 22 Apr 20:00hrs. As i Said i am zero in scripting.

Comment: you can look into the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-windows-programs-on-a-schedule/), don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: Thanx Again. you said "dont forget to accept the answer" how do i accept it.

Comment: Thanx Again. you said "dont forget to accept the answer" how do i accept it. how to change the command into a program so i can run it with Windows Task Scheduler

Comment: You don't need to transform it into a program vlc itself is already a program, you can just paste the command that you already have in the "Program/script" textbox on the action window to make it launch, as for accepting the answer I think it's just clicking in the mark sign next to it. Good Luck.

Comment: why is it .ts file? is it appropriate to use it for radio stream?