# Add current date to a file via task scheduler

Tags: vlc-media-player, scheduled-tasks, rtsp, cctv

I need to automate some CCTV stuff, since the software of the manufacturer doesn't work properly.

I found this: [Automate VLC schedule recording](https://superuser.com/questions/586112/automate-vlc-schedule-recording)

I scheduled it daily and it works fine, but it overwrites the file every day. I figured that a solution would be to add the current date to each file name.

How do I need to change it to make it work?

I have tried a lot and gooled for hours, but I can't make it work.

For example I have tried:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:31344 :sout=#duplicate{dst=file{dst=C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\record_&%DATE&.ts},dst=display} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep --run-time=3600 vlc://quit

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler to always use the same file name, and in your scheduled script
check if the file exists and rename it.

For an example batch script see the post
[cmd line rename file with date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984391/cmd-line-rename-file-with-date-and-time).

Comment: Thank you. I will do it like that. Seems to be pretty easy.